# How to calculate square root in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, square-root

I have a project for square root calculation to get the larger side of in a right triangle using Pythagorean theorem.

Here's what I've tried :

```
@echo off
set /p a=Pleas Enter Value(1) = 
echo.
set /p b=Pleas Enter Value(2) = 
set /a c=%a%*%a%
set /a d=%b%*%b%
set /a F=%d%+%c%
echo.
:calculation Value(3)
rem root Number
√%F%
echo.
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

**Batch**

This is the native batch method(not accurate):

```
set divider=0
:loop
set /a divider=divider+1
set /a sqrt=F / divider
if %divider% equ %sqrt% goto break
if %divider% gtr %sqrt% goto break
goto loop
:break
echo %sqrt%
```

It will floor the number if the square root is floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

Again, will not support floating point arithmetic, but this code works:

```
@echo off

Title SquareRoot
:StartSquareRoot
cls
echo Number:
set /p number=
call :SquareRoot %number%
echo Square: %number%
echo Root: %answer%
pause
goto StartSquareRoot

:SquareRoot
set root=1    
set /a sqr=%root%*%root%
:Loop
if %sqr% LSS %number% (
    set /a root=root+1
    set /a sqr=root*root
    goto Loop
)
(EndLocal && set answer=%root% && exit /B)
```